# UIViewController orientation problems in iPad

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I am presenting MFMailComposeViewController as modal from a view controller (lets call it xyz) added to nav stack. When user clicks on cancel button, the MFMailComposeViewController is dismissed. This works fine when xyz is added to nav stack in portrait/landscape mode and the device orientation doesn't change until after cancel is clicked.

present modal - alloc init MFMailComposeViewController on a button tap

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:mailController animated:NO];
```

dismiss modal - mailComposeController: didFinishWithResult: error

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If orientation changes between xyz being displayed and the mail view controller canceled, xyz's orientation changes unexpectedly.

For example:

1. Device orientation portrait
2. pushViewController xyz on button tap
3. change device orientation to landscape, all views are rotated as expected
4. present MFMailComposeViewController
5. mail controller displayed on landscape mode
6. tap on cancel or send email
7. xyz orientation rotated 90 degrees (unexpected) - expected: xyz orientation shouldn't change.

I don't know what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ok so i couldn't fix the weirdness. It had something to do with the modal view controller trying to present a UINavigationController (MFMailComposeController) from withint my navigation controller. 

As a work around, I used UIPopoverController to present MFMailComposeViewController. That worked, but i have a new problem - When the key board is presented when the pop over controller is visible, it scrolls the view inside the pop over controller to the bottom. I tried adjusting the content size but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: have you figured out a solution for that? I am having the same problem. The view simply scrolls to the bottom for every letter typed... very annoying. I hope you can have a solution for that. thanks.